# Can you append to an array inside a dict?

Tags: swift

In Swift, you can declare a dict where the value is an array type, eg:

```
var dict: [Int: [Int]] = [:]
```

However, if you assign an array for a given key:

```
dict[1] = []
```

then it appears that Swift treats the array as immutable.  For example, if we try:

```
(dict[1] as [Int]).append(0) // explicit cast to avoid DictionaryIndex
```

then we get the error 'immutable value of type [Int] has only mutating members named 'append''.

---

If we explicitly make the array mutable, then the append works, but doesn't modify the original array:

```
var arr = dict[1]!
arr.append(0) // OK, but dict[1] is unmodified
```

---

**How can you append to an array which is a dict value?**

More generally, how can you treat the values of a dictionary as mutable?

---

One workaround is to reassign the value afterwards, but this does not seem like good practice at all:

```
var arr = dict[1]!
arr.append(0)
dict[1] = arr
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [swift: modifying arrays inside dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534229/swift-modifying-arrays-inside-dictionaries)

Comment: I really wish that we could have a binding close vote on our own questions as dupes.  That one didn't show up as related until after submission >< (ie http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172002/grant-the-op-a-binding-close-as-duplicate-vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unwrapping the array instead of casting:

```
dict[1]!.append(0)
```

Comment: That does it, thanks!  I saw that `dict[1]` alone was giving me a `DictionaryItem` instead of the array, so it didn't occur to me that swift's type inference would work differently if I unwrapped it.  Duh!