# How do I remove only one of the many values assigned to a key in a Dictionary?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary with an array of potential values for a key. Now I want to be able to remove just one of the values (according to a selection made by the user), but all the examples I find deal with dictionaries that don't contain an array.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't (legally) modify a dictionary key.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [swift: modifying arrays inside dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534229/swift-modifying-arrays-inside-dictionaries).

Comment: Do you want to remove a specific value or at an index?

Comment: @MartinR, unfortunately that post deals only with appending. Theres nothing about removing there...

Comment: @Glenncito: Yes, but the accepted answer shows and explains the general principle. If you understand why and how `dict["key"]?.append(4)` works then  `dict["key"]?.removeAtIndex(index)` is not *too* far away.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a NSMutableDictionary whose values are NSMutableArray objects whose items are NSString objects, right? If so,

1. retrieve the array using the dictionary key

   NSMutableArray *mutableArray = mutableDictionary[key];
2. then delete the object

   [mutableArray removeObject:stringObject];