# Create empty dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary initialized

```
var dictionary = [String: [Double]]()
```

And I want to append

```
dictionary["Hello"].append(0.0)
```

but this gives me error "nil".

I tried to solve this by

```
extension Dictionary { 

    func appendish(key: String, value: Double) {

        if self[key] == nil {

            this give me error "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"
        }
    } 
}
```

How do I solve this? Been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding the "nil" error for `dictionary["Hello"] = [1, 2, 3, 4] `? A screenshot might help.

Comment: @Arc676 Updated the question description. I meant dictionary["Hello"].append(0.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift: modifying arrays inside dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24534229/2976878) (Although you'll have to first assign a value to the key "Hello")

Answer (score 3):

Subscripting a `Dictionary` with a key returns an optional of type `Value?`. In your case, `dictionary["Hello"]` returns a `[Double]?`. This optionality models the possibility that the dictionary doesn't contain a value for the given key.

If you're only dealing with static data, it's best to just use a literal expression:

```
let dictionary = [
    "Hello": [0.0]
]
```

If you're using dynamic data, then there are several ways to do what you're trying to achieve, depending on how you would like to handle the `nil` case:

1. Use optional chaining

   ```
   dictionary["Hello"]?.append(0.0)
   ```

   - This appends to the array stored for the key `"Hello"`, but does nothing if there's no such value for that key.
   - This has the downside of making bugs harder to catch, because the consequence of the silent `nil` case might not be observed until long after this part of the code has run.
2. Use force unwrapping

   ```
   dictionary["Hello"]!.append(0.0)
   ```

   - This appends to the array stored for the key `"Hello"`, but crashes the program if there's no such value for that key.
   - Unlike optional chaining, this makes it easy to catch the point of failure at runtime. Of course, it comes with the drawback of crashing your program.
3. Handle the nil case in your own way

   ```
   if var array = dictionary["Hello"] {
       dictionary["Hello"] = nil // This line is a performance optimisation that removes the need for array to be copied
       array.append(0.0)
       dictionary["Hello"] = array
   }
   else {
       print("No array for the key \"Hello\"") // Handle this as you wish
   }
   ```

Comment: optional chaining with things returned from a dictionary won't work most of the time because the returned value is a temporary.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this? Seemed to work fine when I tested it

Comment: You are right, the copy behavior seems to have been changed somehow in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this. Firstly, this is incorrect code:

```
dictionary["Hello"].append(0.0)
```

There might not be an array associated with the key "Hello", in which case `nil` will be returned by the subscript of the dictionary. So you need to unwrap it, either forced or un-forced:

```
dictionary["Hello"]?.append(0.0)
// or
dictionary["Hello"]!.append(0.0)
```

But I think what you really want to do is

```
if dictionary["Hello"] != nil {
    dictionary["Hello"]!.append(0.0)
} else {
    dictionary["Hello"] = [0.0]
}
```

After a long time of fiddling around with extensions and stuff (I am not familiar with this area of swift), I finally wrote the method `appendish` method that you were intended to write:

```
extension Dictionary where Value : RangeReplaceableCollection & ExpressibleByArrayLiteral, Value.Iterator.Element == Value.Element {
    mutating func appendish(key: Key, value: Value.Element) {
        if self[key] != nil {
            self[key]!.append(value)
        } else {
            self[key] = [value]
        }
    }
}

// test
var dict = [String: [Double]]()
dict.appendish(key: "Hello", value: 0.0)
```

Comment: No need to create your own `Appendable` protocol – `RangeReplaceableCollection` and `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` should be sufficient.

Comment: @Hamish Sorry but I am not very familiar with extending a generic type. I was finding a protocol that has an `append` method as well but I couldn't find one. However, I can't seem to add the generic constraint that says "implements both `RangeReplaceableCollection` and `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`" using `where Value: RangeReplaceableCollection, ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`. Can you edit the answer?

Comment: @Hamish I tried it but it fails to compile with message: "cannot assign value of type '[Value.Iterator.Element]' to type '_?'" on the line `self[key] = [value]` which is quite weird...

Comment: Ah, you need to add an extra constraint as the `Element` associated types must be the same, so `where Value : RangeReplaceableCollection & ExpressibleByArrayLiteral, Value.Iterator.Element == Value.Element` :) You could also do it solely with `RangeReplaceableCollection` conformance (e.g see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/dd6b523deaa6284245ba21559bf4b65a)).

Comment: @Hamish Thanks. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary look up returns an *Optional* value because the key might not exist, in which case it returns `nil`.

If your intention is to append to the array if it exists or create one if there isn't one yet, then the *nil coalescing operator* `??` comes in handy:

```
var dict = [String: [Double]]()

dict["hello"] = (dict["hello"] ?? []) + [1]
print(dict) // ["hello": [1.0]]

dict["hello"] = (dict["hello"] ?? []) + [2]
print(dict) // ["hello": [1.0, 2.0]]
```

This method does create a new array instead of mutating the existing one.